# Module six not found, although module six is installed

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, six

I cannot run jupyter lab as it complains about module six. Module six is already installed with conda. I even tried to install with pip too, but it says it is already installed and doesn't do anything. So, what to do here?

```
jupyter lab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ilyas\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\ilyas\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ilyas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 11, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.application import JupyterApp, base_aliases
  File "c:\users\ilyas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 30, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
  File "c:\users\ilyas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .traitlets import *
  File "c:\users\ilyas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 57, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

I tried to remove with conda, and then re-install but that also did not work:

```
conda remove six
RemoveError: This operation will remove conda without replacing it with
another version of conda.
```

Install with pip:

```
pip install six
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\ilyas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.12.0)

python -m pip install six
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\ilyas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.12.0)
```

Environment:

- Windows 10
- python 3.7
- jupyter-lab 1.0.0a3
- six 1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

you are installing `six` for Python 2, but trying to use it from Python 3.

install for Python 3 with:

`python3 -m pip install six`

Comment: python3 -m pip install six
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: As I said "six" is already there. Why do I even need to install again? And python3 is unrecognized, is this normal?

Comment: you have it installed in a different interpreter than you are running

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following but still NOT solved:

I had to do this in the following error:

```
pip uninstall six

pip install six
```

Then I get the the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server'` error.

So I install `jupyter_server` with conda, and now the jupyter lab is working.

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_server
```

Even though the notebook is opening, I could not import packages. Checking the command prompt was showing the jupyterlab-manager was outdated. So, did the following:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Still, the notebook opens but cannot do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

few years late but I had the same problem. To add a little to what Corey was saying. I think you need to install it via Conda to use it in Conda (and hence Jupyter), i.e.

> conda install six